# Getting "None" while parsing JS page with bs4 lib

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am getting "None" when I execute a simple program. I have checked previously answered questions but all of them are related to function and I am not using a function in this program. Kindly explain this concept to me. Thanks

Below is the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.talabat.com/uae/restaurant/46038/al-mamzar?aid=1191")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
category = soup.find(class_="panel ng-scope ng-isolate-scope panel-default")
print(category)
```

Comment: `ng-scope` et al. suggest that you're expecting Angular to load - you're *only* getting the HTML, no JS will run. Do you see anything with that class in the response content?

Comment: I see. I don't see anything in response. I chose the hardest and most complicated web page(according to my newbie knowledge) to practice web scraping. How do I distinguish between JS and HTML pages?

Comment: There are a few ways. You can look in your browser network tab to see if there are lots of requests for JavaScript content. You can `print(soup.prettify())` to see what HTML you actually receive.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. I am going to explore more about it before I start to write code to scrape a page.

Answer (score 0):

I  was trying to parse a JS page with bs4 lib. bs4 lib parses only HTML pages.

Comment: I'd suggest just deleting the question then.